# JTable - Adding, editing, removing rows

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jtable, abstracttablemodel

Please help me, what can I do if i want to add a new row, edit rows and remove rows from my table? I was trying to do something but it doesn't work. (The table opens csv files where columns are separated by `;`, for example a row looks like this:

> Mike;Tyson;50;mike@tyson.com;123123123

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class T1Data extends JPanel {
    private final JTable table;
    private MyModel model;
    private JPanel buttonsPanel;
    static File currentFile;    //remember edited file

    public T1Data() {
        super(new BorderLayout(3, 3));

        model = new MyModel();
        table = new JTable(model);
        table.setModel(model);
        this.table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(700, 70));
        this.table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

        JPanel ButtonOpen = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        add(ButtonOpen, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        // Create the scroll pane and add the table to it.
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        // Add the scroll pane to this panel.
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //Create button panel
        buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonsPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(5, 50, 5));

        //add 'Open button
        JButton open = new JButton("Open...");
        buttonsPanel.add(open);
        //add 'Add' button
        JButton add = new JButton("Add row");
        buttonsPanel.add(add);
        //add 'Remove' button
        JButton remove = new JButton("Remove row");
        buttonsPanel.add(remove);
        //add 'Save' button
        JButton save = new JButton("Save");
        buttonsPanel.add(save);
        //add 'Save as...' button
        JButton saveAs = new JButton("Save As...");
        buttonsPanel.add(saveAs);

        //add buttonPanel to Frame
        add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        // add a nice border
        setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));

        //'Open' button action
        open.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                JFileChooser fileopen = new JFileChooser();
                FileFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
                        "Text/CSV file", "txt", "csv");
                fileopen.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);

                int ret = fileopen.showDialog(null, "Choose file");

                if (ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

                    // Read Text file
                    File file = fileopen.getSelectedFile();
                    T1Data.currentFile = file;
                    CSVFile Rd = new CSVFile();
                    MyModel NewModel = new MyModel();
                    table.setModel(NewModel);
                    ArrayList<String[]> Rs2 = Rd.ReadCSVfile(file);
                    NewModel.AddCSVData(Rs2);
                    System.out.println("Rows: " + NewModel.getRowCount());
                    System.out.println("Cols: " + NewModel.getColumnCount());
                }
            }
        });
        //'Add row' button action
        /*
        add.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    int row = table.getSelectedRow();
                    if (row!=-1) model.deleteRow(row);
                }
            }
       });
       */
        //'Remove row' button action
        remove.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    int row = table.getSelectedRow();
                    if (row!=-1) model.deleteRow(row);
                }
            });

        //'Save' button action
        save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                try{
                   //the file path
                   File file = currentFile;
                   //if the file not exist create one
                   if(!file.exists()){
                        file.createNewFile();
                   }

                   FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
                   BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

                   //loop for jtable rows
                   for(int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++){
                   //loop for jtable column
                       for(int j = 0; j < table.getColumnCount(); j++){
                             bw.write(table.getModel().getValueAt(i, j)+";");
                       }
                    //break line at the begin 
                    //break line at the end 
                    bw.write("\r\n");
                    }
                    //close BufferedWriter
                    bw.close();
                    //close FileWriter 
                    fw.close();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Dane zostały zapisane.");

                    }catch(Exception ex){
                       ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
        });


        //'Save As...' button action
        saveAs.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                try{

                    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser(".");
                    int status = chooser.showSaveDialog(T1Data.this);
                    if (status == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

                        //the file path
                        File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                        //if the file not exist create one
                        if(!file.exists()){
                            file.createNewFile();
                        }

                        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
                        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

                        //loop for jtable rows
                        for(int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++){
                            //loop for jtable column
                            for(int j = 0; j < table.getColumnCount(); j++){
                                bw.write(table.getModel().getValueAt(i, j)+";");
                            }
                            //break line at the begin 
                            //break line at the end 
                            bw.write("\r\n");
                        }
                        //close BufferedWriter
                        bw.close();
                        //close FileWriter 
                        fw.close();
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File saved.");
                    }
                 }catch(Exception ex){
                     ex.printStackTrace();
                 }
            }
        });
    }

    // Method for reading CSV file
    public class CSVFile {
        private final ArrayList<String[]> Rs = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        private String[] OneRow;

        public ArrayList<String[]> ReadCSVfile(File DataFile) {
            try {
                BufferedReader brd = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(DataFile));
                while (brd.ready()) {
                    String st = brd.readLine();
                    OneRow = st.split(";"); // OneRow = st.split(",|\\s|;");
                    Rs.add(OneRow);
                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(OneRow));
                } // end of while
            } // end of try
            catch (Exception e) {
                String errmsg = e.getMessage();
                System.out.println("File not found:" + errmsg);
            } // end of Catch
            return Rs;
        }// end of ReadFile method


    }// end of CSVFile class

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        // Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("T1Data");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        // Create and set up the content pane.
        T1Data newContentPane = new T1Data();
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);
        // Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    class MyModel extends AbstractTableModel {
        //public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) { return true; }  //CELL EDITING
        private final String[] columnNames = { "Name", "Surname", "Age", "Email", "Telephone"};
        private ArrayList<String[]> Data = new ArrayList<String[]>();

        public void AddCSVData(ArrayList<String[]> DataIn) {
            this.Data = DataIn;
            this.fireTableDataChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columnNames.length;// length;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return Data.size();
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return columnNames[col];
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            return Data.get(row)[col];
        }

        /*
         DOESN'T WORK!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!1
        // Deletes the given row
        public void deleteRow(int row) {
            if (row == -1) return;

            Data.remove(row);
            fireTableRowsDeleted(row, row);
        }
        */
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        // creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you remove some of this extra code?

Comment: @jaa232 see answers by MadProgrammer about [JTable + AbstractTableModel + ArrayList](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A992484+[jtable]+abstracttablemodel+arraylist+is%3Aanswer) he's referrence, most active in AbstractTableModel v.s. various array types

Answer (score 2):

When you load in a `File` in the `open` JButton `ActionListener`, the code creates a new `TableModel` and sets the `JTable` model:

```
MyModel NewModel = new MyModel();
table.setModel(NewModel);
```

The `NewModel` instance is local to this method, thus any changes to the instance variable `model` will not be reflected in the `JTable` (in other words, `model != table.getModel()`). Instead of creating a local variable, set the instance variable to the new model. For example:

```
model = new MyModel();//sets the instance variable to the new model
table.setModel(NewModel);
```

In this way, whenever code refers to `model`, it is acting on the current `TableModel` of the `JTable`. Alternatively, when making changes to the `TableModel`, you can get the model directly from the `JTable`, casting if necessary:

```
remove.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int row = table.getSelectedRow();
        MyModel myModel = (MyModel)table.getModel();//get the model directly
        if (row!=-1) myModel .deleteRow(row);
    }
});
```

Comment: 1. OP has AbstractTableModel (success with DefaultTableModel too, can be better and esier for OP), 2. both models (by ignoring their parent TableModel) has method for reseting, both models can to add a new row, delete... (those methods are implemented in APIs), 3. not good answer

Comment: Whether `AbstractTableModel` *or* `DefaultTableModel`, with current posted code after open's actionListener is called, any calls attempting to change `model` are referencing `model`, which is *not* the current `TableModel`

Comment: @mKorbel: copeg's answer does get to the root of why calling methods on the model variable won't work -- because it references the wrong TableModel object. Better to set the model field correctly, or call `table.getModel()` whenever the model is needed as he states. 1+

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels OP has typos in deleteRow (inside AbstractTableModel), without notifier fireTableRowsDeleted nothing will be repainted in the JTables view (next JTables repaint can ends with NPE (edit not NPE but an ArraysIndexWhateverException) from models count no rows v.s tables:-), answer is simple wrong :-), nothing solving, btw MadProgramer starting here with very similair answers, do you/if you remember, and now is everywhere with excelent answers